# Css swap scrollbar issue

Tags: html, css

I am working on a template and I can’t understand one thing, more precisely why it happens I understand, but how to do it cross-browser?

There is a fixed block, initially the scroll in it is not available, but an empty scroll bar is displayed (from the body) so that the image does not jump into the carousel. Then, when clicking, the scrollbar is replaced and the scrollbar of this block (.content-wrapper) is displayed

However, this only works in Chrome, in other browsers the scrollbar (.content-wrapper) disappears under the carousel ...

Is there a cross-browser solution?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        body {
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        body.scroll {
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }

        .content-wrapper {
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;
        }

        body.scroll .content-wrapper {
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        .carousel-wrapper {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .content {
            position: relative;
            background-color: rgba(241, 156, 187, 0.5);
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body onclick="this.setAttribute('class', 'scroll')">
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="carousel-wrapper">
        <div class="cover"></div>
        <div id="carouselSlides" class="carousel slide carousel-fade align-self-sm-center align-self-md-start"
             data-ride="carousel" data-interval="7500"
             data-pause="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active"><img
                        src="https://store-images.s-microsoft.com/image/apps.18496.14408192455588579.aafb3426-654c-4eb2-b7f4-43639bdd3d75.2c522ca4-9686-4ee2-a4ac-cdbfaf92c618?mode=scale&q=90&h=1080&w=1920"
                        class="d-block min-vw-100" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item"><img
                        src="https://149351115.v2.pressablecdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Stack-Gives-Back-2018-.png"
                        class="d-block min-vw-100" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="content" style="height: 10000px">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I achieved the desired result, almost 100%, as usual IE does a feint ...

Tell me, who faced this behavior, is there a hack for him?

When scrolling down, a fixed block leaves 1px, only in IE (Edge)

[image]

Layout corrections:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        body {
            position: fixed;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            width: 100%;
        }

        body.scroll {
            position: relative;
        }

        .carousel-wrapper {
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
    <div class="cover"></div>
    <div id="carouselSlides" class="carousel slide carousel-fade align-self-sm-center align-self-md-start"
         data-ride="carousel" data-interval="7500"
         data-pause="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active"><img
                    src="https://store-images.s-microsoft.com/image/apps.18496.14408192455588579.aafb3426-654c-4eb2-b7f4-43639bdd3d75.2c522ca4-9686-4ee2-a4ac-cdbfaf92c618?mode=scale&q=90&h=1080&w=1920"
                    class="d-block min-vw-100" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item"><img
                    src="https://149351115.v2.pressablecdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Stack-Gives-Back-2018-.png"
                    class="d-block min-vw-100" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper container-fluid">
    <div class="content" style="height: 10000px">
        content
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('body').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('scroll');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```